# Permission denied for docker-compose Superset

Tags: docker, docker-compose, superscript

I am trying to get the Superset running on ubuntu server. I have referenced the steps from Superset page as below:

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/
cd incubator-superset/contrib/docker
# prefix with SUPERSET_LOAD_EXAMPLES=yes to load examples:
docker-compose run --rm superset ./docker-init.sh
# you can run this command everytime you need to start superset now:
docker-compose up
```

I have fixed the initial issues around right version of docker-compose and postgress address bind issue on port 5432. So after fixing those my docker compose run command

```
docker-compose run --rm superset ./docker-init.sh
```

works fine and it asks me to set up a user name and password.

Finally to get the container running I run the final command

```
docker-compose up.
```

On my mac, it would run redis, postrgre container and then give me a localhost:8088 for me to get access to Superset UI with login info.

However on Ubuntu, when I run that, I first get this:

[image]

So looks it is running redis and postgres containers fine.

But then it is giving me Permission denied errors to create some mkdir directory.

[image]

Pls note I am running it as root user.

Also, my docker compose version is fine with 1.23.2 and my docker along with docker-compose is installed under

```
/usr/bin/docker and not /usr/local/bin/docker.
```

But I think that shouldn't be an issue.

Any help where it is going wrong and how can I fix it?

Thanks

Edit:

Ok I looked at the same issue mentioned on Github. And used a suggestion of using it only for Production and not development in docker-compose.yml file.

It seems to not throw the same error now when I do

```
docker-compose up.
```

[image]

However when I open localhost:8088 it does not connect to the UI.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```sh
mkdir ../../assets
chmod -R 777 ../../superset/assets/
```

as set in [docker-compose.yml#L64](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/blob/master/contrib/docker/docker-compose.yml#L64), it is using `../../superset` as volume when in develop. However the container does not have any permission in the host so the solution is to make a directory by yourself and grant the necessary permissions on to it.